# Continuity of volume of boundary of Riemannian manifolds in the Gromov-Hausdorff sense

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

Let $\{X_i^n\}$ be a sequence of smooth compact Riemannian $n$-dimensional manifolds with boundary. Assume that this sequence has uniformy bounded below sectional curvature, and each $X_i$ is geodesically locally convex near its boundary (the latter assumption is equivalent that $X_i$ is an Alexandrov space). Assume $\{X_i\}$ converges in the Gromov-Hausdorff sense to a compact smooth Riemannian manifold $X$ with boundary and $\dim X=n$, i.e. there is no collapse.

> Is it true that volume of the bondary $vol_{n-1}(\partial X_i)$ converges to $vol_{n-1}(\partial X)$? The case $n=2$ is already interesting to me.

**Remarks.** (1) By the Perelman stability theorem $X_i$ is homeomorphic to $X$ for $i\gg 1$.

(2) By Burago-Gromov-Perelman one has convergence of volumes of manifolds $vol_n(X_i)\to vol_n(X)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The statement holds for a sequence of extremal susbsets (not necessary boundary).]

According to Theorem 1.2. in my "Applications of quasigeodesics and gradient curves",
$\partial X_i\to \partial X$ as length spaces in the sense of Gromov--Hausdorff.
Then the same argument as in Burago--Gromov--Perelman shows that $\mathrm{vol}\,\partial X_i\to \mathrm{vol}\,\partial X$.

Comment: Could you please state more precisely what statement holds for extremal subsets (in Alexandrov spaces I guess).

Comment: Are the following statements true? Let $\{X_i^n\}$ be sequence of compact Alexandrov spaces with curvature uniformly bounded below which GH-converges to $X$ without collapse. Let $F_i\subset X_i$ be extremal subsets (e.g. boundaries) which converge is Hausdorff sense to $F\subset X$. Then: (1) $F$ is extremal subset of $X$. (2) $F_i\to F$ is GH-sense. (3) For large $i$ all $F_i$ and $F$ have the same Hausdorff dimension which is necessarily integer $k$. (4) $vol_k(F_i)\to vol_k(F)$ where $vol_k$ is the $k$th Hausdorff measure which is necessarily finite and positive for $F_i$ and $F$.

Comment: @MKO  (1) yes --- it follows  since F is ideal of gradient flow, (2) For sure yes, moreover they converge as length-spaces, (3) yes, I am not sure if it stated this way somewhere, but there is a way to estimate volume of ambient space (better say $R$-nbhd of $F$ in the ambient space via area of $F$); hence if $F_i$ is collapsing, than so is $X_i$; (4) I already said yes (did I?).

Comment: In relation to (3), this can also be seen from the fact that the stability theorem respects extremal subsets. Kapovitch showed this for a sequence of single subsets (arxiv.org/abs/math/0703002) and it is not to hard to generalize to multiple subsets - Searle and I wrote it up in arxiv.org/abs/1209.1366